# Connecting with teradatasql returns wrong non-latin characters

Tags: python, teradata

I'm trying to connect with teradata with code is as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(f'teradatasql://{HOST}/?logmech=KRB5')
with engine.connect() as conn:
    df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

This works, but data wth non-latin characters is transformed into wrong ones. For example
instead of `Siemianowice Śląskie` I get `Siemianowice \x8cl¥skie`.
I'm aware of the fact that I can't change charset with `teradatasql`, but its default is `utf-8` which, if I recall correctly, should have no problem with this set of characters. What's going on here?

Comment: Most likely the source column in the database is incorrectly defined as LATIN, and those characters are not in the Teradata server LATIN repertoire. The "client ASCII to/from server LATIN" mapping does no translation, so it's possible to misuse it to load and retrieve an arbitrary sequence of bytes. But server LATIN to client UTF8 does do translation, returning the corresponding UNICODE character for each (assumed to be) LATIN code point.

Comment: @Fred I forgot to mention that when trying to connect with `teradata.UdaExec.connect()`, the data was correctly loaded. Is it possible for column to be incorrectly defined despite that fact? Is `udaexec` doing something that `teradatasql` doesn't under the hood?

Comment: Yes. UdaExec uses ODBC which defaults to ASCII not UTF8. Technically the data is loaded *incorrectly* with client locale character set being stored in what is defined as server LATIN.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Fred. So to understand it fully,, since UdaExec uses ASCII, shouldn't the non-latin characters be impossible to encode? Or if I got this right, UdaExec doesn't care what is stored in that column as long as its configuration is LATIN, and returns values as-is? On the other hand `teradatasql` tries to encode values into unicode, and only then are they changed "correctly" into what they've been defined as - LATIN, hence the modified characters?

Comment: Close. ODBC defaults to ASCII session character set (though other options are available). And with the ASCII option there is no translation, the driver / database just *assume* the client data is compatible with Teradata LATIN - so you can store and retrieve any sequence of bytes unchanged as far as the driver is concerned. But the teradatasql driver expects to be working with Unicode strings (as does Python3) so if the source column is LATIN it does a Teradata LATIN to Unicode translation first.